# What's the opposite of "dogmatic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I'm trying to describe an approach that doesn't just blindly follow established opinion, but seeks validation through experimentation. Any ideas?

Comment: Catmatic, of course.

Comment: @PeterOlson - I was going to say Vegematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context of your description, I would offer **pragmatic**. From [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pragmatic):

> prag·mat·ic
>
> 1. Dealing or concerned with facts or actual occurrences; practical.

Though, this may not be connotatively sound given your circumstance, so you could perhaps go with **empirical**. Again, from [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/empirical):

> em·pir·i·cal
>
> 1. Relying on or derived from observation or experiment: empirical results that supported the hypothesis.
> 2. Verifiable or provable by means of observation or experiment: empirical laws.

Both of these terms are often used in science in relation to experimentation.

Comment: OP's *seeks validation through experimentation* criteria makes empiricism (empirical, empiricist) the best antonym for dogmatic. +1.

Answer (score 6):

I would go with *flexible* or *open-minded.* The general idea is being unconstrained by common go-to rules.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess an extreme opposite would be [skeptic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skeptic):

> Someone who habitually doubts beliefs and claims presented as accepted by others, requiring strong evidence before accepting any belief or claim.

Comment: This is a good answer, because both dogmatic and skeptic connote extreme positions.

Answer (score 2):

How about [*amenable* :](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amenable)

> 1.Willing to respond to persuasion or suggestions.
>   2.Willing to comply with; agreeable.

There are the alternatives:

> Uncertain
>   Diffident
>   Flexible
>   Impressionable

Answer (score -2):

Antonyms for dogmatic:

- ambiguous
- equivocal
- impartial
- indefinite
- vague
- willing
- yielding
- amenable

Comment: Hi, @Bill Braaten, welcome to ELU. Please note the above site message re: answer length. Given the number of options you've offered, it would be helpful to offer a short definition of each antonym in order to more clearly understand the differences between them, as well as how well they work as answers to the question.

Comment: the answer did not require excess verbiage,  and was complete,

Comment: These adjectives are opposite to what characterizes dogmatism (inflexibility, etc.) however there is no single adjective among them which I satisfying consider an antonym to "dogmatic". I would go for "pragmatic" as per another answer.